# Rails convert datetimepicker date string to datetime data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I am building a To Do List application with Ruby on Rails, and each item in my `Task` resource has a `deadline` attribute that is created with the gem `'datetimepicker'`.

This `'datetimepicker'` gem pulls in dates as a `string` data type with the format `"12/13/2012"`, `"%m/%d/%Y"`.

I am trying to group `task` elements by the day value in their `deadline` attribute. I've found one article on how to do this (although I think it contains one typo):

https://ariejan.net/2007/01/12/rails-group-results-by-week-using-group_by/

However, I'd rather do the work in the `tasks_controller` than the `task` model (maybe the model is the cleaner way to do it? I am a nuby and open to suggestions on this).

I've found another article on the `group_by` method that demonstrates an approximate process:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month?view=asciicast

This article looks a little cleaner to me. It requires me to use the `.beginng_of_day` method to treat all `task` items with the same day value in their `deadline` equally.

I'm running into an issue with both methods, which is that they treat `deadline` like a `datetime` data type. I want to use the `.to_datetime` method to convert `task.deadline`, but the `'datetimepicker'` gem formats the `deadline` `string` in precisely the wrong way for `.to_datetime` to convert it:

> "12/13/2012".to_datetime          # => ArgumentError: invalid date

see => apidock[dot]com[slash]rails[slash]String[slash]to_datetime

I've found a similar article that recommends re-formatting the `deadline` attribute with the `.strptime` and `.strftime` methods, but I don't see how to do this when `deadline` is a `string` and not a `datetime`:

see => stackoverflow[dot]com[slash]questions[slash]16296885[slash]how-to-convert-datetime-picker-value-to-datetime-in-ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me make this conversion, or suggest a different (preferably simpler!) strategy for grouping tasks by day?

Thanks for your help, and apologies for the broken links; I don't have sufficient reputation points to embed more than 2 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you actually want a date? not a datetime?

In any case you can use

```
Date.strptime("12/13/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")
=> #<Date: 2012-12-13 ((2456275j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

DateTime.strptime("12/13/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")
=> #<DateTime: 2012-12-13T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456275j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: i could use dates and omit the '.beginning_of_day' method, but then don't i lose the time data from the task? i want to group tasks by date but still display the time afterward.

Comment: If the column for tasks is a datetime then no, you won't.

Comment: yes. i've opted to use a 'datetime' instead of a 'date', and group by day using '.to_date' method. thank you for your help re-formatting.